# R-creating multiple data frames with names

Tags: r

I want to create 100 empty data frames with names

- df1, df2, ...,df100.

Each data frame will have 2 columns where

- i'th data frame dfi have columns with colnames  "yi" and "xi".  For example, df5 's column names will be y5 and x5.
- first column will be chracter and second one will be numeric.

How can I create such data frames using R. I will be very glad for any help. Many thanks.

Comment: Are these character or numeric columns?

Comment: akrun, I edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create the empty 'data.frames' in a list using `replicate` and change the column names with `Map`

```
n <- 100
lst <- replicate(n,data.frame(y=character(), x=numeric(),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE), simplify=FALSE)

names(lst) <- paste0('df', 1:n)
nmy <- paste0('y', 1:n)
nmx <- paste0('x', 1:n)
lst1 <- Map(function(x,y,z) {names(x) <- c(y,z); x}, lst, nmy, nmx)
```

Or

```
lst1 <- Map(setNames, lst, as.data.frame(rbind(nmy,nmx)))


str(lst1, list.len=3)
#List of 100
# $ df1  :'data.frame': 0 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ y1: chr(0) 
#  ..$ x1: num(0) 
# $ df2  :'data.frame': 0 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ y2: chr(0) 
#  ..$ x2: num(0) 
# $ df3  :'data.frame': 0 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ y3: chr(0) 
#  ..$ x3: num(0) 
# [list output truncated]
```

Comment: +nicely done @akrun, good to see use of Map.
if you need these data frames in the global environment, do this list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobaEnv)

Comment: @infominer Thanks for reminding the `list2env`.  I initially thought about that.

Comment: Nope, don't use `list2env`. What on earth would you do with 100 empty data sets in the global environment??