# Creating list of randomized data-frames with increasing number in names

Tags: r, random

I want to create 10 (at work: 50,000) random data-frames with setting seed for sake of reproducibility. The seed should be different for each data-frame, also its name should increase from df_01, df_02 ... to df_10. With help of @akrun 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353613/r-creating-multiple-data-frames-with-names) I coded a loop like this:

```
# Number of data-frames to be created
n <- 10

# setting a seed vector
x <- 42

# loop
for (i in 1:10) {
        set.seed(x)
        a <- rnorm(10,.9,.05)
        b <- sample(8:200,10,replace=TRUE)
        c <- rnorm(10,80,30)
        lst <- replicate(i, data.frame(a,b,c), simplify=FALSE)
        x <- x+i
}

# name data-frames
names(lst) <- paste0('df', 1:10)
```

Now I have my data-frames, but it seems I can't get he random generation running. All data are similar. When I replace the lst-line with following code at least the seeded randomization works:

```
print(data.frame(a,b,c))
```

A crackajack extra would be a hint for leading zeros in the dfs-names in order to sort them.

Any help appreciated, thx!

Comment: You used `set.seed(42)`.  If you remove that, it should be random.  Or perhaps `n1 <-sample(5000, 1); set.seed(n1)`

Comment: Even with settiing.seed only once code didn't produce different frames, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same results in all your list elements, because you create your list from scratch in every iteration using `replicate` and replace the previously created one. If you are using a `for` loop, you do not need `replicate`.

For the sake of reproducability I would create a vector of seeds before the loop and then set the seed in each iteration. The leading zeros can be produced using `sprintf`:

```
## Number of random data frames to create:
n <- 10

## Sample vector of seeds:
initSeed <- 1234
set.seed(initSeed)
seedVec <- sample.int(n = 1e8, size = n, replace = FALSE)

## loop:
lst <- lapply(1:n, function(i){
            set.seed(seedVec[i])
            a <- rnorm(10,.9,.05)
            b <- sample(8:200,10,replace=TRUE)
            c <- rnorm(10,80,30)
            data.frame(a,b,c)
        })
## Set names with leading zeroes (2 digits). If you want
## three digits, change "%02d" to "%03d" etc.
names(lst) <- paste0('df', sprintf("%02d", 1:10))
```

Comment: Ok, didn't know about seed vectors. Great solution thanks, seems to be working fine! Sorry for not commenting my code, I've edited that.

Comment: What is the use of `initSeed <- 1234; set.seed(initSeed)` rather than `set.seed(1234)`?

Comment: There's no difference, really. You can use both.